# update too slow from table with one record

Tags: mysql

Please consider the table bd.nn that contains roughly 19 million records:

```
> SELECT n, name, cdf from bd.nn limit 4;
+-------+-------------------------------+--------+
| n     | name                          | cdf    |
+-------+-------------------------------+--------+
| 10002 | JOJE                          | NULL   |
| 10010 | AUGUSTINA                     | NULL   |
| 10029 | CARDOS                        | NULL   |
| 10037 | DE FRITOS                     | NULL   |
+-------+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Primary key in `n` with BTREE type.

The task is to UPDATE field cdf from the following table;

```
> SELECT * from n_cdf_temp;
+-------+--------+
| n     | cdf    |
+-------+--------+
| 10002 | 16     |
+-------+--------+
```

Primary key in `n` with BTREE type.
Both `n` fields still have `char(9)` type although it's planned to move to `int` type.

This table only has one record as an example but should have some million lines as well.

The commands I tried were, by this order:

```
UPDATE bd.nn y SET cdf = (SELECT cdf from temp.n_cdf_temp t WHERE t.n = y.n);

UPDATE bd.nn y SET cdf = (SELECT cdf from temp.n_cdf_temp t WHERE t.n = y.n) WHERE y.n in (SELECT n from temp.n_cdf_temp WHERE cdf IS NOT NULL);

UPDATE bd.nn y INNER JOIN temp.n_cdf_temp t ON y.n=t.n SET y.cdf = t.cdf;

UPDATE bd.nn y FORCE KEY (PRIMARY) INNER JOIN temp.n_cdf_temp t ON y.n=t.n SET y.cdf = t.cdf;
```

The problem is that this update takes a long time.
In my development laptop (Core 2 Duo) with MyISAM tables, the update for the fourth command took 6,5 seconds and for the third about 30 seconds.
If n_cdf_temp has 1000 records, the MyISAM engine takes 45 seconds.

But in the production server, with InnoDB tables, the update took 14 minutes when n_cdf_temp had only one record.
When n_cdf_temp had 1000 records, the query took ca. 18 minutes.
MySQL version 5.0.67 in old Linux box P4, 1GB RAM.

What else should I do to greatly improve the UPDATE performance for acceptable time?

ETA EXPLAIN for SELECT version of queries 3:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT y.n, t.cdf from bd.nn y INNER JOIN temp.n_cdf_temp t ON y.n=t.n\G 
** 1. row id: 1 select_type: SIMPLE table: t type: index possible_keys: PRIMARY key: cdf key_len: 2 ref: NULL rows: 1 Extra: Using index 
** 2. row id: 1 select_type: SIMPLE table: y type: ALL possible_keys: PRIMARY key: NULL key_len: NULL ref: NULL rows: 18744700 Extra: Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) –
```

Comment: could you post the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT bc.nn y INNER JOIN temp.n.cdf_temp t ON y.n-t.n` and a similar `EXPLAIN` for query 4?  Also, does your join table have to be in temp db? Is temp db on the same computer as bd db?

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT y.n, t.cdf from  bd.nn y INNER JOIN temp.n_cdf_temp t ON y.n=t.n\G

** 1. row
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: cdf
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
** 2. row
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: y
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 18744700
        Extra: Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the EXPLAIN you posted, it appears that it is refusing to use the index on your 'y' table.  In row 2 of the EXPLAIN, note **'key: NULL key_len: NULL'**.  Is it possible that the datatypes for the primary keys of the 2 tables are different?

Comment: Right on the spot. I had already started the process of changing `n` to `int` in the `temp` table, which I didn't recall.  The 1000 records were updated in 0.09 seconds now.  Thank you very much dnagirl!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem: make 2 requests.

One is: 
SELECT cdf from n_cdf_temp WHERE n = 'X';

Second:
UPDATE bd.nn y SET cdf = 'result of first request' WHERE n = 'X';

Sure, the method is not ideal, but it very simple and it works.

Or you want update table for all values of 'X'?

Comment: Maybe faster to create new table as a result of: `SELECT x.n, x.name, y.cdf from bd.nn x, n_cdf_temp y WHERE x.n = y.n;` ? But i think that if you want to manipulate with a millions of records - you must be ready that it will be very slow. Check that indexes for field `n` used